# x86 asm changing char array values

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

I have an array like this:

```
msg_values db "a=   b=   "
```

And I need to insert char, lets say '5' after 'a=' to get:

```
"a=5  b=   "
```

Can somebody give an example how to do it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write to the address of the array, offset by the index of the element you want to change. The exact syntax would depend on which assembler you use. For example, it could be:

```
mov byte ptr [msg_values+2], '5'
```

or just

```
mov byte [msg_values+2], '5'
```

You could also load the address into a register and use register-indirect addressing:

```
lea esi, [msg_values]
mov byte ptr [esi+2], '5'
```

Comment: lea bx, msg_values ;
mov ds[bx], '1' ;
inc bx ;
mov ds[bx], '2' ;
inc bx ;
mov ds[bx], '3' ;

I just found this solution, it is similar with yours, but I use different registers, it looks like working, is there everything ok?

Comment: Well, it looks like real-mode code, but the principle is the same. You don't need to use a register if you just want to replace a single character.

Answer (score 0):

To do that (in NASM syntax):

```
mov [msg_values+2], byte '5'
```

Some other assemblers want `byte ptr` instead of only `byte`.